# How to rotate an object vertically and horizontally in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

So currently for the object I am testing, I'm trying to figure out how to rotate the object vertically and horizontally. I know the code for both. In addition, my object is rotated when I click and drag on the object.

```
Vertical :      gl.glRotatef(angle, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
Horizontal :    gl.glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

I feel like I am not grasping a concept or missing a step. I wanted to know if I could get some advice.

Comment: There's a nice tutorial for both OpenGL and matrices math here:

http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/

Comment: glRotatef is actually a quaternion rotation (an angle of rotation and a normalized vector about which to do the rotation).  The rotation doesn't need to be about one of the principal (x, y, z) axes, it can be about any generally defined axis.  Most of the tutorials I've seen talk about matrices for rotations about each of the principle axes.  To understand the more general glRotate, you'l need to understand quaternions.